# "Unable to autoload constant" after upgrading from Rails 4.2 to 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, jruby

I am trying to upgrade my Ruby version from 4.2 to 5.2 but i am getting the following error :

> org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) Unable to autoload
> constant PaymentAccounts::VersionsController, expected
> /local/home/nndri/workplace/pcui-upgrade/src/PaymentContractUIWebsite/rails-root/app/controllers/payment_accounts/versions_controller.rb
> to define it

```ruby
# development.rb
config.cache_classes = false
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
config.eager_load_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/')]  
config.eager_load = false
```

```ruby
# versions_controller.rb
class PaymentAccounts::VersionsController < ApplicationController
  include PaymentAccountsHelper

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

directory structure:

```
app
  controllers
    payment_accounts
      versions_controller.rb
  helpers
    payment_accounts_helpers.rb
  models
    paymentAccount.rb
```

- Added more info about directories.

Comment: HI, where is your `VersionsController` file?  As the error message says, it expects to see it in `app/controllers/payment_accounts/versions_controller.rb` but can't see it there.  If there IS a file there, can you add it (at least the top 10 lines or so) to your question?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn added the file in the question.